# Safety of using `ValidationRule` to extract current setting on back-end table during active connections

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have inherited databases in Access (2000 and 2007-2010) that have validation rules set on the tables. One or more rules are blocking a handful of records during an append. I don't see any issues with the data, so I need to understand which rules are set in order to troubleshoot.

The append destination database is split (v2000). The back end is in a shared location on a P2P and each user has a local front end.

I'd really like to fix this today, instead of waiting until off-hours to enter design mode in the back end. I don't want to break any connections, or risk corruption.

I'm considering writing code using the `ValidationRule` property in VBA to see if I can return the current rule (not even sure if that will work), but am worried that it will interrupt connections.

I know that using any of the built-in "Database Tools" causes interruptions, I'm not clear on whether it's due to the routine or accessing these settings in general that requires exclusive use. I also know that any DDL action can cause issues during non-exclusive use, and returning the property value seems to ride that line.

Does anyone know whether this is safe?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but to *analyze* the validation rules, you can simply open the linked tables in the frontend in design view. Those properties will be read-only, but to see them it's enough.

Comment: @Andre perhaps you're right. I've always been cautious accessing backend objects while in shared mode because I've had it drop connections before, but that may have been before we split the db. Checking a back up copy will get me what I need without risk. Maybe I'll test these solutions on a weekend though just to better understand how shared mode is affected during design changes. I'll delete this question since it's pretty clear I'm just confused. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just open the backend(s) with Access in shared mode to study the table designs.

Changes can be made as well, if the table is not in use.

But I would certainly *wait to off-hours* and start with creating a backup of the backend(s), open the backend(s) exclusively, make the changes, and test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the destination table is the most heavily used. There is some link or aggregation of this data in most forms so any time I enter design mode the connections are dropped. Assuming my backups have been made, do I have any backdoor options at all in shared mode?

Comment: Even though the backend file is in use, you should be able to make a simple file copy of it. It may not contain the exact last tenths of a second changes but should be readable anyway. Check the main tables and/or run a repair/compact on it.